# What is _fini as defined by gprof output?

Tags: gfortran, gprof

I am using gprof to profile my code and it says that 96.4% of the time is spent in `_fini`. I have no subroutine named this and the underscore makes me think it is something which I am not officially writing. What is `_fini` and how do I go about optimizing this section of the code or the way the compiler uses `_fini`?

If it matters I am writing in Fortan90 and using gfortran to compile. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [*this doc*](http://autosysprogs.blogspot.com/2012/02/init-and-fini-obsolete-functions.html), `_fini` is a function that used to be included in libraries, and it would be called whenever the library was unloaded.

It can also be a symptom of lots of objects being created and destroyed (under the covers where you can't see it).
`gprof` often points to functions when the reason for the slowness is elsewhere.
That's just one of its many problems.

If you're trying to eliminate waste cycles from your program, [*here's what a lot of people do*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), and it works.